# How does Dependency Injection Work in dynamically loaded components

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Given that I have my components and services setup like this and both Module A and B are lazy loaded. The component container in module A will be dynamically loading component B1. In this case how would the dependency injection work? Does it search for the dependencies from Module A or Module B?

I'm designing something like a dashboard with widgets where Module A will be the Dashboard whereas Module B will just be a any modules with components where it will act like a widget when being rendered by the container in Dashboard.

Will Component B2 will be able to resolve the dependency of Service B when being dynamically loaded in the container of Module A?

If no, is there a way to achieve this, without the services being provided in root.

[image]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'widget-container',
  templateUrl: './widget-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget-container.component.scss'],
})
export class WidgetContainerComponent {
  @Input() widget!: WidgetModel;

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  container!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    const imported = await import(
        `../../../../modules/${this.widget.module}/components/${this.widget.name}/${this.widget.name}.component`
      );
    const componentName = Object.keys(imported).find(x => x.endsWith('Component'))!;
    const componentClass = imported[componentName];

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentClass);
    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent<any>(componentFactory);
    componentRef.instance['settings'] = this.widget.settings;

    componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following URL tells about a cached copy of the service for each component.
https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-services-in-modules-vs-components